# Copper: best to dig with a Shovel or to mine with a Pickaxe?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Considering copper deposits on the surface of the ground, which one will give me a better yield of Copper Ore: Shovel or Pickaxe?

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=402